# BentoML CORS error on loading swagger docs in k8s deployment

Tags: bentoml

This is similar to https://github.com/bentoml/BentoML/issues/1909, except i am doing k8s deployment and couldn't figure out where to put `bento_config.yaml` stuff in k8s config. Current config

```
apiVersion: serving.yatai.ai/v2alpha1
kind: BentoDeployment
metadata:
  name: isleroyale
spec:
  autoscaling:
    maxReplicas: 10
    minReplicas: 2
  bento: isleroyale
  ingress:
    enabled: true
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 4000m
      memory: 4Gi
    requests:
      cpu: 2000m
      memory: 3Gi
  envs:
    - name: BENTOML_CONFIG_OPTIONS
      value: >-
        tracing.exporter_type=otlp
```

I am trying to load swagger from react app (backstage https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-catalog/) and getting cors issue - considering k8s deployment, how to enable cors?

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:8080/isleroyale/docs.json' from origin 'http:localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that configuration can be overridden [Overriding configuration with environment variables](https://docs.bentoml.org/en/latest/guides/configuration.html#overriding-configuration-with-environment-variables) and CORS can be enabled with [http config](https://docs.bentoml.org/en/latest/guides/configuration.html#http) server config with `BENTOML_CONFIG_OPTIONS` env variable

```
    envs:
      - name: BENTOML_CONFIG_OPTIONS
        value: >-
          api_server.http.cors.enabled=true
          api_server.http.cors.access_control_allow_origin=https://services.localhost.8080
          api_server.http.cors.access_control_allow_methods[0]=GET
          api_server.http.cors.access_control_allow_methods[1]=OPTIONS
          api_server.http.cors.access_control_allow_methods[2]=HEAD
```

Comment: hello do you know how to add the configuration when deploying? I'm getting cors error with my deployed bentoml api. is there a way the config file can be added in the build?

Comment: did you check the link @DiegoFranco on answer? you need to modify your config with api_server:
  http:
    envs: ...